# R Keras error in k_get_session(): No attribute 'get_session'

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When I try to run `sess <- k_get_session()`, I get the following error message

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_session'
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Keras is version 2.3.1, and Tensorflow is version 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

which version of Keras and TensorFlow do you have installed?

I think the issue here is that you are using tensorflow v2, while the get_session function is supported for version v1.

This should enable the v1 of tensorflow:

```
library(tensorflow)
use_compat("v1")
```

Let me know if this solves you issue.

Comment: Keras is version 2.3.1, and Tensorflow is version 2.1.0. Using the above didn't solve the issue. Same error message as before